# Error: No forward-proxy ports configured

Tags: proxy, squid, transparency

I'm trying to set up a transparent proxy for a school project but i have this error:
error: No forward-proxy ports configured
while trying to configure squid from the /etc/squid/squid.conf file (squid v.4.13)
I tried : http_port 192.168.100.252:3128 transparent
but i still have the same error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i found a configuration file for the squid.conf file but i still get the error above.
i am trying to make a transparent proxy on a debian router